# full path from fileupload using javascript

Tags: java, javascript, eclipse, file-upload

Hi I want file path from the user input. I read multiple questions online mine isn't about getting full path from file upload. I already know it is not possible, according to browser security settings I can only get filename and not the whole filepath. So I request the user to enter the full path , but problem is now when I read the path the '/' get substituted for ':'

Ex :

Input

```
/Users/hardisk/Downloads/clipcanvas_14348_offline.mp4
```

changes to

```
:Users:harddisk:Downloads:clipcanvas_14348_offline.mp4
```

Please help.

I am attaching the code here

```
<input type="file" id="file" name="file"/> 

function upload_video()
        {
            filename=document.getElementById("file").value;
            alert("uploading"+filename);
            window.location.href="VideoUpload?file="+filename;  
        }
```

Comment: do you have any code?

Comment: You can easily get down votes, please enter some code,either explain this question more..

Comment: sorry added the code now.

Comment: does the alert box actually show `:Users:harddisk:Downloads:clipcanvas_14348_offline.mp4`, after inputting `/Users/hardisk/Downloads/clipcanvas_14348_offline.mp4`? that's strange.

Comment: and by the way, in the case that you're trying to get the user to upload files like this -- it won't work. asking the user to input the local file path will not give you access to the file, besides being a bad user experience.

Comment: java and javascript is not same. i changed it for you!

Comment: @gengkev well then could you suggest me a better alternative apart from the criticism please.

Comment: sorry if i sounded impolite - i was just wondering if you wanted to upload a file, which is a common use case. if that isn't the case, sorry for the misunderstanding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I solved it by myself. Not a great solution just a workaround.

With the filename am also asking the user to enter file path and then combining the two and storing.

Here's code for it:

```
<form action="VideoUpload" method="get" id="upload_form">
                <input type="file" id="file" name="file"/> 
                <input type="text" id="path" name="path"/> 
                <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit"/>
            </form>


String name=request.getParameter("file");
        String path=request.getParameter("path");
        String filename=path+name;
```

It is a workaround till I find a better solution.